# Why when I addChild while animating rotationY in Flash, why do some of my children appear blank unless I interact with them once?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, flash-builder

I have Korean vocab flash cards that "flip" (using `Actuate` animation library) when you tap them. This is what happens:

1. TAP: Actuate `Card.rotationY` to 90 over 0.2 seconds
2. `removeChild(koreanWord);` `addChild(englishExplaination);`
3. Actuate Card.rotationY to 180 over 0.2 seconds

When I do this, sometimes parts of `koreanWord` are blank until I interact with them!

Then when I flip back and do something similar, sometimes other pieces will disappear. Sometimes instead of the Korean, my card background will disappear, sometimes the English description will disappear.

It seems pretty inconsistent, but I have realized that when I test on my Nexus5 (1080x1920), more items will go blank then when I test on my desktop debugger (480x760). Could this have something to do with it caching to bitmap?

Has anyone seen something like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for posterity:

I was able to force it to render missing parts by `Actuate`ing the alpha on flip, that worked, although I'm going to go back and find if there's a lower cpu-requirement way of doing this.